# table reflow with scrollbar in tbody

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I using bootstrap 4 to style the table reflow. My question is I don't know how to add scrollbar into the tbody to enable user who can scroll by horizontal orientation. And I also have a question if some one know how to make the css to display the table as table-reflow (which bootstrap already done but the bootstrap is currently in the alpha-dev. So cannot use the bootstrap-alpha into my production.)

this is the example table.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<style>

</style>
<body>



    <table class="table table-reflow">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Table heading</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
          <th>Table heading</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
          <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>




    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: To make it short... so, you need a table with scrollable body and fixed headers? Where is your current CSS? What have you tried and why it did not worked?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan curretly I'm using the bootstrap v4 because I'm not good in css and the bootstrap v3 doesn't support table-reflow. Yes, the user only can scroll the body and fixed headers. It's would be good if you can help me create some basic css for reflow table because I don't know how to make my own css to make table reflow.